# How to find and collect Objects to Map by its parameter?

Tags: java, lambda, stream, java-stream

Given enum:

```
enum Type {
  PRIMARY,
  SECONDARY
}
```

and two different Sets of Objects with same parameter (**type**):

```
class OldObject {
  Long id;
  Type type;
}

class NewObject {
  Long id;
  String title;
  Type type;
}
```

...which looks like:

```
Set<OldObject> ...
Set<NewObject> ...
```

Beeing confused about Stream API with *Collectors* and *Groupings* I am not able to finish with a **Map[OldObject, NewObject]** with pairs grouped by **Type**. I am able to guarantee that both sets ale full and I am able to find pairs. I thought that I can start with **stream of enum** (but do not know if it is a good aproach):

```
Map<OldObject, NewObject> pairs = Optional.of(Schema.values())...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment my code looks like:

```java
        Map<OldObject, NewObject> compared = new HashMap<>();

        Arrays.stream(Type.values()).collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(s ->
                compared.put(
                        oldObjectsSet.stream()
                                .filter(o -> o.getType().equals(s))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElseThrow(),
                        newObjectsSet.stream()
                                .filter(m -> m.getType().equals(s))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElseThrow()
                ));
```

...which works but does not look great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really going for Streams, the simplest approach would be to go for something like

```
Map<Type, OldObject> oldObjectMap = oldObjectSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(OldObject::getType, Function.identity()))
Map<Type, NewObject> newObjectMap = newObjectSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NewObject::getType, Function.identity()))

Map<OldObject, NewObject> pairs = Arrays
    .stream(Type.values())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(oldObjectMap::get, newObjectMap::get))
```

Note that this approach will likely run into errors if some enum is not present in one of the sets because the map collector doesn't support null values.
You can prevent that by adding a filter call just before this happens:

```
Map<OldObject, NewObject> pairs = Arrays
    .stream(Type.values())
    .filter(oldObjectSet::contains)
    .filter(newObjectSet::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(oldObjectMap::get, newObjectMap::get))
```

Comment: You're completely right, I will edit my answer shortly, hang on

Comment: As I wrote I am sure about those objects so I can simply use Stream on both sets and filter by Type. Gimme a moment, I will try this solution!

Comment: Still doesn't work, as the sets will not have only two elements. Which will throw a Duplicate element exception

Comment: @Lino OP stated that they guarantee they are "able to find pairs", so how would that work with duplicate keys?